# Shell not executing VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, shell

I am trying to execute the shell script in vb.net.

```
 Shell("C:\Program Files\NCBI\blast-2.2.25+\bin\similarity\blastn -query test.fasta -db database.txt -outfmt 10 -out out.txt")
```

The script doesn't create the outfile mentioned in -out switch. The path mentioned is correct and also the command with switches is correct. It runs well in command prompt but not in the program.

Thanks

---

### Update

I used process class but still the outfile is not produced.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ComponentModel
Dim myProcess As New Process()
 Try
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\NCBI\blast-2.2.25+\bin\similarity\"
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "blastn.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-query test.fasta -db database -outfmt 10 -out out.txt"
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        myProcess.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
 End Try
```

Comment: did you try with blastn.exe instead of blastn ?

Comment: Well, it probably creates the file, you just can't find it back.  Use the Process class instead, it gives you much better control over the program you start.  You'll want to set the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.

Comment: Doesn't work with blastn.exe either

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood, actually the file is being executed, and it is just the output that is not being done right?

Comment: yaaa.. something like that.. I'm reading about the process class

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't being created? Have you searched your computer? Since you haven't specified a path, just a file, it might be getting created in whatever working directory you are currently in.

Comment: That might be the case.. let me check

Comment: @SpectralGhost u were right..

Comment: Converted to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a path, just a file, it is getting created in whatever working directory you are currently in.